# Plotting a LASSO model with "mtcars" dataset in R

Tags: r, regression, glmnet, lasso-regression

I have recently been made aware of LASSO. As it looks a bit complicated I tried to find an example using `mtcars`. The following code produces a plot of the independent variables:

```
library("glmnet")
lasso <- glmnet(as.matrix(mtcars[-1]), mtcars[,1], standardize=TRUE, alpha =1)
plot(lasso)
```

It does so however without showing which line is which variable.

[This](http://www.pmean.com/16/images/lasso.pdf) explains it, but I cannot figure out which part of the code I need.

[This source](https://beta.vu.nl/nl/Images/werkstuk-fonti_tcm235-836234.pdf) is a bit easier to read but does not provide the plot code.

Can someone help me figure out which variable is which line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plot(lasso, label = TRUE)`. Then check `rownames(lasso$beta)`. The `i`-th variable is labeled by numerical value `i` in the plot. For a quicker loopup, you can do make a table:

```
setNames(rownames(lasso$beta), 1:nrow(lasso$beta))
```

You probably did not realize that you can check `?plot.glmnet`. Or probably you've checked `?plot` but found nothing there. Yes, looking for documentation of a generic function on some methods is not straightforward.

The package vignette, either the [old version](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) or the [latest version](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnet_beta.pdf), also covers this labeling issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the variable number to the plot with:

```
plot(lasso, label=T)
```

You can get the coefficient numbers with:

```
mycoefs <- coef(lasso)@Dimnames[[1]][-1]
cbind(1:length(mycoefs), mycoefs)
```